# Same application started in multiple app pools

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I just expierienced something in IIS that i can't understand, and I'm hoping that someone else might do :) ?

I have one site in IIS, with multiple applications. All of them are configured with a serviceAutostartProvider, and they are set up like this:

```
-Production (site, points to c:\prod)
   * App1 (uses appPool 1, points to c:\prod\app1)
   * App2 (uses appPool 2, points to c:\prod\app2)
   * App3 (uses appPool 3, points to c:\prod\app3)
```

The applications are mapped to different paths on disk (like above), and the applications have different assemblies in the /bin folder. They have nothing in common except for some "common" .net assemblies like the autostartprovider.

Once I deployed App3, i could see that it started automaticaly (since it's configured with the autostartprovider), but it booted TWICE!?

Once in appPool3 (as expected) and once in appPool1.

I could see this in my logs since the autostartprovider reads an appSetting (the applications name) from web.config and log's it with the w3wp processid. In other words, the logs showed:

```
"Booted App3, processid: {appPool3's id}"
"Booted App3, processid: {appPool1's id}"
```

How can this happen? Am I missing something obvious? I've verified that the App3 files/assemblies didnt end up in the path for App1 by mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a confirmed bug in IIS, see the following KB:

[Some services are preloaded unexpectedly on an IIS server in Windows KB2672277](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2672277)